# Настройка ЧПУ для категорий и подкатегорий

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, чпу

На моем сайте есть каталог услуг.
Я реализовал по задумке через записи. Каждая категория - рубрика, каждая запись - услуга.
В постоянных ссылках прописал `/%category%/%postname%/`

Но столкнулся с проблемой в ЧПУ.

`catalog` - Категория 1 уровня

`pogruzchiki` - Категория 2 уровня

При переходе по адресу `/catalog/pogruzchiki/`  - страница с услугами отображается корректно.

Но категория 2 уровня так же доступна по адресу `/pogruzchiki/` .

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить данное поведение и добиться чтобы категории 2 уровня были доступны только после родителя.

Установлен плагин "No Category Base (WPML)"

Comment: У меня стоит прекрасный плагин wp clearfy, попробуйте избавиться от дубликатов с помощью него.

Answer (score 0):

Описанное вами поведение возникает как раз из-за плагина No Category Base (WPML).

Суть этого плагина как раз в том, чтобы исключить обязательное наличие родительской категории. По умолчанию этот плагин должен перенаправлять страницы вида `/catalog/pogruzchiki/` на `/pogruzchiki/` с кодом ответа сервера 301. Судя по вашему описанию он работает некорректно.

Чтобы ваши категории 2-го уровня были доступны только после родителя вам придется отключить этот плагин.

Comment: Если я отключаю этот плагин, то категорию доступны по следующему адресу - /category/catalog/pogruzchiki/ . Я установил этот плагин, чтобы убрать /category/